# Android - How can I set single layout for multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner. I am developing an application where am facing a strange problem with layout.
WHen I run my application in small devices it works fine, but when I run it on big screen device its layout properties changes automatically. 
Please let me know if there is any way that I can create a single layout programatically for all screen sizes?
my xml is,

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/contents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/panchangtab1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBtn1"
                android:background="@drawable/horoscopetab1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here I am getting first image ok but second image is not in actual size.

Comment: find the screen size and fix it thro code by setting margins in java

Comment: @Ashish Patil you should not give any fixed value to the component that u've used in application.Set component width and height as "match_parent","wrap_content","fill_parent".

Answer (score 3):

You have to use fill_parent , match_parent , wrap_content units for width and height of the layouts.....and also you have to use weight for layouts instead hard coding the height and width.

check this link for multi screen supporting layouts......
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

use **weightsum** in declaration of your layout will help you.

```
       <LinearLayout

                android:weightSum="100"   //This is horizontal layout so will work for width
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"


                 >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:layout_weight="40" //40% for text1
                    android:layout_height="40dp"  
                    >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_weight="60" //60% for text2
                    android:layout_height="50dp"  

                    >
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you know anything for relative layout for adjusting width ?

Comment: For relative : You should use match_parent and wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following web site for developing multiple screen support application.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html (Follow the sub links also) http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use match_parent and wrap_content on your layout file. Use them in RelativeLayout or LinearLayout or bla bla.

If you want a ImageView, TextView, Button... was covered whole screen width, you should use **fill_parent** on **layout_width**. Also, if you want a ImageView, TextView, Button... was covered whole screen height, you should use **fill_parent** on **layout_height**.

You can check this [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use match_parent, wrap_content, fill_parent etc. like attribute, dont create hard coded layouts file. Use 9 patch images, not static, not all the case satisfies your condition to use 9 patch, but when you found that some images can work in 9 patch so make it 9 patch, this is only for ImageView not for all component, remaining things TextViews, EditText etc. You can create with your own, BUT DONT CREATE HARD CODED LAYOUT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different qualifiers to create multiple layouts for different screens like this :

```
layout-hdpi/mylayout
```

you should read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) .